# How to get specific value from DB by id

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

How to get specific value from DB by id.
This is my table: `TABLE-RECORDS`-(name of table)  and `KEY-ID` , `KEY-PRICE` ... I'm trying to get `KEY-PRICE` by `KEY-ID` and can not. How to do it?

Comment: Add some code of your query

Comment: By using cursor or select statement with where args you can perform this action.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

// please change the column names of database if i have mistaken

```
public Cursor getCursor(int id) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String from[] = {"key-price"};//this is the edit1
String where = "key-id=?";//this is the edit2
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)+""}; //this is the edit3
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, table-records, from, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
return cursor;
}
```

//just call this function and see the magic

```
private int getPrice(int id) {

    Cursor c = getCursor(id);
 int price=-1;
    if(c != null)
    {
        while(c.moveToNext){
              //assuming price is an integer
              price = c.getInt(0);//edit 4

            // use these strings as you want
        }
    }
return  price;
}
```

Comment: its give me this error:                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

Comment: I have changed the code again please check. please update if you face any error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but this is the query.

```
SELECT key-price FROM table-record WHERE key-id='id number you need';
```